# Fold/unfold only the div I select instead of all?

Tags: php, jquery, html, fold

Greetings,

I am a newbie who just started with jQuery. I am building a basic PHP app for our team that displays a list of open helpdesk tickets.

To avoid cluttering the screen, I only want to display the title of the ticket and if clicked, its description.

Here's my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Animate my Div</title>
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            a {                    text-decoration: none;                }
            #expand {                    background-color: #fff;                }
            #mydiv {                    display: none;                }
        </style>
        <script src="jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").click(function(){   $("div").slideToggle(1000);                });
            });            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $con = mysql_connect("korg", "joe", "bob");
        if (!$con) {                die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());   }
        mysql_select_db("wfr11", $con);
        $result = mysql_query(" select title, description from webcases");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        ?>
            <p><a href="#expand"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></a></p>
            <div id="mydiv"><?php echo $row['description']; ?></div>
        <?php
        }            mysql_close($con);            ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Right now, my code works but unfolds all the divs for all open tickets, regardless of what ticket name I clicked.

Ideally, I'd like to show the description of for the ticket name I clicked. Not all of them. Is it possible?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entirely possible, yes.

First issue you have is that you are repeating an ID in the loop, HTML IDs must be unique.  I would suggest using a class there.  Wrap the two components together in a DIV to make them in to a combined item that can be dealt with individually as well

```
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
<div class="entry">
    <p><a href="#expand"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></a></p>
    <div class="description"><?php echo $row['description']; ?></div>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Then, you need to make your jQuery select just the adjacent description DIV.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".entry a").click(function() {
    $(this).parents('.entry').find('.description').slideToggle(1000);
  });
});
```

Remember to use `htmlentities()` on your echo's from the database if they are not already in proper HTML form.

Comment: @Orbling: your solution worked like a charm!! All I had to do was creating two CSS classes for "  .description {display: none;         }" and "entry       {margin: 0; padding: 0px;}".

Comment: Is this.parentS() better suites since it won't select the root element?. Another post below suggest using this.parent()...can someone please explain?

Comment: `.parent()` gets the immediate parent of an element, whilst `.parents(selector)` gets all parents matching a certain selector.  If you use `.closest(selector)` that functions like `.parents()` but only picks the first ancestor as opposed to all matching.  The way I have it set up allows for the HTML structure to alter a little whilst still retaining the functionality - assuming an anchor inside an 'entry' class had an element with the 'description' class that can be slid.

Comment: @Chris Is it all working for you then, question closed, or do you need more help?

Comment: @orbling. It is working, thank you. Question closed. I am new so is there a way to mark this thread closed and vote for you?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you're after a toggle. Maybe use an id to select the divs you want rather than just the plain div.

```
$(".link_class").click(function(){   $("#my_div").slideToggle(1000);                });
```

Target particular divs by assigning a class to the link.